# DataTables events don't work with data option

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using DataTables 1.11.3 and load data by ajax like this, and all events catchers work ok. But if I remove ajax option and put "data": ta_data, events don't work at all, no one. Then if I put by button 'cklick' ajax source and redraw events work again Events don't work with static load data from local variable data ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";

   
    const ta_data = JSON.parse(ta).data;
    
    let table_arch = $("#datatable-archive").DataTable({
            "scrollY": '60vh',
            "scrollX": false,
            "paging": false,
            "searching": false,
            "info": false,
            "order": [[ 10, "desc" ]],
            "ajax": {
               "url": 'rest/data/history/' + last_date,
               "error": function(a,b,c){showErrorModal(a,b,c); offSpinner();}
        },
            
    })
      .on( 'preDraw', function() {sp = {buy:0, sell:0, buyErr:0, sellErr:0};})
      .on( 'draw.dt', function() {
            $.when(offSpinner()).then(
                function(){
                    gageMaker(sp, "Accuracy");
                    commonDonut();
                }
            )
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to change order. First set event catchers then initialize the table

```
const ta_data = JSON.parse(ta).data;

let table_arch = $("#datatable-archive"))
  .on( 'draw.dt', function() {
        $.when(offSpinner()).then(
            function(){
                gageMaker(sp, "Accuracy");
                commonDonut();
            }
        )
}).DataTable({
        "scrollY": '60vh',
        "scrollX": false,
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "info": false,
        "order": [[ 10, "desc" ]],
        "data" : ta_data
    },
        
})
```